# Wildfly treating concurrency management as transactional

Tags: java, jboss, transactions

I had a class that looked like this:

```
@Singleton
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
@Lock(LockType.WRITE)
@AccessTimeout(value = 20, unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
public class MyClass{

    public void someLongRunningQuery(){

    }

}
```

However, this would fail with:

`org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back`

I was able to resolve this by adding this annotation.

`@TransactionTimeout(value = 20, unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)`

My question is - why is jboss treating this method as a transaction? My understanding is the concurrency management and transaction management are different things.

Comment: does the `someLongRunningQuery()` involves in a Transactional scope.

Answer (score 0):

Transaction timeout handling is not defined in EJB spec and JBoss uses a separate transaction management module to do that. Your example points at a REST access to your singleton - is the Singleton also a REST endpoint or is it invoked from some REST endpoint bean?  Just a couple of ideas:
If you have a REST endpoint that injects your singleton and invokes the long running op, isn't it by any chance a `@Stateless` bean? EJB beans are transaction enabled by default, therefore if a client(REST endpoint) initiates a transaction(it does by default - `@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRED)`), your singleton will also participate in the same transaction, but because its invocation takes longer than the default transaction timeout value(300s) it causes transaction rollback. If you do not need a transaction on the rest layer, try disabling it with `@TransactionAttribute(NOT_SUPPORTED)`
If you invoke this long running op from REST layer, wouldn't it be better to use `@Asynchronous` and return some kind of request/job handle to the client, so that it can query the status of the operation instead of waiting and blocking while it finishes? Keep in mind that EJBs are pooled resources, therefore invoking this long op multiple times can drain your pool and cause acquisition timeouts.